# Android Media Player cannot play audio file by the path

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that finds my phone audio files' path, so I pretty sure the path I got is correct. I can play the raw file when I was doing the testing, but I can't play the audio by the absolute path of the storage, the app just crashed when I click the play button

```
//This testing code works
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_audio1)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

```
//setDataSource does not work for me
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Music/thomasF1.mp3"))
mediaPlayer.prepare()
mediaPlayer.start()
```

```
//This does not work for me as well
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Music/thomasF1.mp3")
mediaPlayer.start()
```

```
//manifest xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mediaplayer">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
...
```

```
//in the MainActivity.kt
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.i("mpdebug", "onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        list = getAudioDirectories()

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), requestCode)
        } else {
            Log.i("mpdebug", list.toString())
            Log.i("mpdebug", "permission granted")
            initListeners()
        }
    }
```

```
private fun initListeners() {

        // Start the media player
        playBtn.setOnClickListener {
            if (pause) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.currentPosition)
                mediaPlayer.start()
                pause = false
                Toast.makeText(this, "media playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {

                val path =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/Music/thomasF1.mp3"
                    Log.i("mpdebug path", path)
                try {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, Uri.parse(path))
//                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(applicationContext, R.raw.sample_audio1)//                   
                    mediaPlayer.start()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.i("mpdebug", e.toString())
                }
Toast.makeText(this, "media playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
...
}
```

Comment: your given permission read internal stroge

Comment: @ThavaSelvan   I have given the read external storage permission, do I need other permission?

Comment: Runtime permission granded?

Comment: @ThavaSelvan The permission is granted. "permission granted" has logged at the if else statement

Comment: I found that in the logcat `com.example.mediaplayer D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/thomasF1.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` What did I do incorrectly regarding on granting the permission?

Comment: give these permission in manifest and check runtime also <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207571/discussion-between-thavaselvan-and-hy-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define permission in manifest file, and check and request to permission  before play media, don't deny external storage permission because we play media from internal storage and parse into URI.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
> ```

```
musicUrl = "yourURL";
try {
   mPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(musicUrl));
   mPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I tried the try catch, and I got this  `I/mpdebug: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MediaPlayer.create(appli…Context, Uri.parse(path)) must not be null` I also got the message from logcat : `com.example.mediaplayer D/MediaPlayer: create failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Music/thomasF1.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` What did I do wrong at the code regarding the permission?

Comment: mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

Comment: please do it above setDataSource()

Comment: thank you, I used prepare() rather prepareAsync() and it works

Comment: Great Working! :-)

Answer (score 0):

### please check first permission runtime and also manifirst file and try this way

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Music/thomasF1.mp3";
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse(path));
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });
```